# should existing watchOS apps be updated?

Tags: ios, app-store, watchkit, apple-watch

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04222016a

The above blog post says "all new watchOS apps submitted".

In reference to this blog post. Should I updated my existing watchOS 1 app? Can I update my main app with, leaving the watchOS1 app as it is?

Answer (score 4):

Just confirmed with apple that, its only for new submissions and existing apps can still update it without supporting watchOS2.

Comment: "confirmed with apple", did you ask some kind of tech support about this?

Comment: Yes. I contacted apple developer support.