# Can you build an app for iOS 8.2 - 9.x with a WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, watchkit

I've seen in passing that Apple is about to require all apps with WatchKit support to move to WatchKit 2.0.

However, it seems that WatchKit 2.0 requires iOS 9.x.

I have an app I've been developing for a client since iOS 6. (Yes, iOS 6!)

The client had me add fairly simply WatchKit support (basically just custom local notifications with action buttons.)

The app is currently targeted to iOS >= 8.0, and the client would like to continue to support iOS 8.x (Requiring 8.2 or 8.4 would probably be acceptable, but the client wants to support some flavor of 8.x)

Is there a way to deploy an app with an embedded WatchKit app that runs on iOS 8.x and 9.x, that meets Apple's upcoming requirement to migrate to native WatchKit 2.0?

---

### Is this the solution?

- Build an iOS app that will run on iOS 8.2 through 9.x
- Build 2 WatchKit targets, one for WatchKit 1.0, and one for WatchKit 2.x, and include both in the app?

If so, will the install process install the correct version of the watch app for the user's WatchKit version?

Comment: I have an app supporting back to iOS 7 that has watchOS 1.0 and 2.0 targets and it correctly installs the correct one based on the user's watchOS version.  Apple's announcement makes it sound like they aren't going to be accepting watchOS 1.0 apps at all anymore though.  Do you know that having a watchOS 2.0 app allows you to submit it with watchOS 1 too?

Comment: @dan I believe the watchOS 2 requirement only applies to *new* iOS apps. [According to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36853173/4151918), Apple will still accept a watchOS 1 app in an updated iOS app.

Comment: My client still hasn't shipped his app for the first time yet, though, and probably won't before June 1, so the new app restriction will probably apply.

Comment: @dan, how do you include both WatchKit 1.0 and 2.0 apps (sub-bundles) in your app bundle? Can you point me to docs on how to do this?